# mask layers : are they ignored by freestyle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, freestyle

does freestyle ignore Mask Layers from the Renders Layers tab ?

I have checked the layers I want to be used as masks, but it doesn't seems to work.

The only way I found for now is to duplicate some meshes on my freestyle layers so that they hide the freestyle lines.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?  Thanks !

Comment: I have a similar issue, freestyle strokes are only applied to one render/view layer.